# $\pi_{2n-1}(\operatorname{SO}(2n))$ element represents the tangent bundle $TS^{2n}$, not torsion and indivisible for $n>1$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, lie-groups

> **Question:  Is the element $\alpha$ in $\pi_{2n-1}(\operatorname{SO}(2n))$ representing the tangent bundle $TS^{2n}$ of the sphere $S^{2n}$ indivisible and not torsion?**

My understanding so far —

An $\operatorname{SO}(2n)$ bundle over $S^{2n}$ corresponds to  an element in $\pi_{2n}\operatorname{BSO}(2n) =\pi_{2n-1}\operatorname{SO}(2n)$.

Not torsion:  There does not exist any integer $m > 0$ such that $m\alpha$ is a trivial element.

Indivisible: There does not exist any integer $k > 1$ and any element $\beta$ in $\pi_{2n-1}\operatorname{SO}(2n)$ such that $\alpha=k\beta$.

Ref: Mimura, Toda: [Topology of Lie groups](https://doi.org/10.1090/mmono/091).  Chapter IV Corollary 6.14.

p.s. I am asking $n>1$ so if you vote down for $n=1$, you may reconsider your vote... Lol

Comment: The generator of $\pi_1(SO(2))$ corresponds to the Hopf bundle $S^3\times_{S^1}\mathbb R^2\to S^2$. The tangent bundle of $S^2$ is twice a generator.

Answer (score 5):

For $n=1$, the answer to your question is negative, as explained by Gregory Arone in the comments.

---

In the cases $n\neq 1,2,4$, there is the following easy argument:

The long exact sequence of the fibration $S^{2n-1}\to BO(2n-1)\to BO(2n)$ induces an exact sequence
$$\pi_{2n}(BSO(2n))\xrightarrow{e} \mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{[TS^{2n-1}]}\pi_{2n-1}(BSO(2n-1)),$$
where $e$ is the evaluation of the Euler class. As the order of $[TS^{2n-1}]\in \pi_{2n-1}(BSO(2n-1))$ is $2$ unless $n=1,2,4$, the image of $e$ is $2\mathbb{Z}$. As $\chi(S^{2n})=2$, we have $e([TS^{2n}])=2$, so $[TS^{2n}]$ must be nontorsion and indivisible as long as $n\neq 1,2,4$.

---

Let me also mention the following convenient description of $\pi_{2n}(BO(2n))$ (this can be used to settle the cases $n=2,4$):

Combining the Euler class with the inclusion $SO(2n)\subset SO$, we have a morphism
$$
(e,s)\colon \pi_{2n}(BO(2n))\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \pi_{2n}(BO)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z} & \text{ if }n\equiv 0,2\text{ (mod) } 4\\
\mathbb{Z}/2 & \text{ if }n\equiv 1\text{ (mod) } 4\\
0 & \text{ if }n\equiv 3\text{ (mod) } 4
\end{cases}.
$$
From Kervaire's [Some nonstable homotopy groups of Lie groups](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-4/issue-2/Some-nonstable-homotopy-groups-of-Lie-groups/10.1215/ijm/1255455861.full), one can deduce that as long as $n\neq 1$ this morphism is injective with image
$$
\begin{cases}
2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z} & \text{ if }n\equiv 0\text{ (mod) } 4,n\neq 2,4\\
\{(k,l)\in\mathbb{Z}^2|k+l\text{ even} \} & \text{ if }n=2,4\\
2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2 & \text{ if }n\equiv 1\text{ (mod) } 4\\
2\mathbb{Z}\oplus 0 & \text{ if }n\equiv 3\text{ (mod) } 4.
\end{cases}
$$
As $S^{2n}$ is stably parallelisable, the image of $[TS^{2n}]$ under this morphism is $(2,0)$, so this class is indivisible and nontorsion.